# Getting error for filtering current_date in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, datetime, filtering

I have 2 queries in Postgresql. Both Queries are used to extract same information.

1st Query----

```
SELECT "pld.PlanDate" 
FROM salesdespatch.sld_cube_salesdespatchdetailshop
WHERE "pld.PlanDate" Between '2023-04-01' AND current_date;
```

2nd Query----

```
SELECT "pld.PlanDate" 
FROM salesdespatch.sld_cube_salesdespatchdetailshop
WHERE "pld.PlanDate" Between '2023-04-01' AND '2023-04-11';
```

When I am running the 1st query, pgAdmin provides an error and the error is explained below.

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text <= date
LINE 2: WHERE "pld.PlanDate" Between '2023-04-01' AND current_date;
                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 96
```

However, the 2nd query is running without any error and I have not changed any syntax in the second query. I have also run Current_date syntax explicitly and it is working fine as well.
I am unable to find what is the source of the error.
Can anyone please explain?

I am also attaching 2 screen shots for the results of 1st and 2nd query for better explanation.

[image: Result of 1st Query]

[image: Result of 2nd Query]

I am trying to filter data between a selected date and current date but got an error that I have explained above.

Comment: **Never**, ever store `date` values in `text` columns.

Comment: Yes, I can now understand source of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the `PlanDate` column is *text*, and not a date type.  Don't store your dates as text.  As a workaround, given that your text dates are in an ISO format, you may cast the column to date in the query:

```sql
SELECT "pld.PlanDate"
FROM salesdespatch.sld_cube_salesdespatchdetailshop
WHERE "pld.PlanDate"::date BETWEEN '2023-04-01' AND current_date;
```

Comment: Than you for the information @Tim Biegeleisen
It did work.

Comment: Done sir @Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

it seems like either date is in text or you can use date(now()) instead of current_date.
date(now()) will work same as current_date.